# How can I improve this for loop based code so it runs faster?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The code below has been working, but I'm afraid that with a couple of thousands rows more, it can get laggy and I was wondering what would be the approach to improve it.

It basically compares 2 datasets by a number common to both and update a couple of columns with their status/checkboxes (TRUE, or FALSE):

```
function onEdit(e) {
if (e.range.getSheet().getName() === 'Todays Tests V2' && e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C3') {
    var formRespSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
    var formRespRng = formRespSheet.getRange(2, 13, formRespSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 4);
    var formRespValues = formRespRng.getValues();

    var todaysTest = e.source.getSheetByName('Todays Tests V2');
    var todaysTestData = todaysTest.getRange(6, 1, todaysTest.getLastRow(), 18).getValues();

    todaysTest.getRange('O6:O').clearContent();
    todaysTest.getRange('Q6:Q').clearContent();
    todaysTest.getRange('R6:R').clearContent();

    for (var i = 0; i < formRespValues.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < todaysTestData.length; j++)
        if (formRespValues[i][1] == todaysTestData[j][1]) {
          if (formRespValues[i][0] == 'Yes') {
            todaysTest.getRange('O' + (6 + j)).setValue('TRUE')
          } else {
            todaysTest.getRange('O' + (6 + j)).setValue('FALSE')
          }
          if (formRespValues[i][2] == 'Yes') {
            todaysTest.getRange('Q' + (6 + j)).setValue('TRUE')
          } else {
            todaysTest.getRange('Q' + (6 + j)).setValue('FALSE')
          }
          if (formRespValues[i][3] == 'Yes') {
            todaysTest.getRange('R' + (6 + j)).setValue('TRUE')
          } else {
            todaysTest.getRange('R' + (6 + j)).setValue('FALSE')
          }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some things that can be further improved with @MisterJojo's answer, see modifications below:

#### Modifications:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() === 'Todays Tests V2' && 
      e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C3') {
    let formRespSheet     = e.source.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1'),
        formRespRng       = formRespSheet.getRange(2, 13, formRespSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 4),
        formRespValues    = formRespRng.getValues(),
        todaysTest        = e.source.getSheetByName('Todays Tests V2'),
        todaysTestNumRows = todaysTest.getLastRow() - 5,
        todaysTestData    = todaysTest.getRange(6, 1, todaysTestNumRows, 18).getValues();

    // this can be replaced with getValues if it feels sluggish
    var inputB    = todaysTestData.map(x => x[1]),
        outputO   = todaysTestData.map(x => [x[14]]), 
        outputQR  = todaysTestData.map(x => [x[16], x[17]]);
        
    for (const frv of formRespValues) {
      let frv0test = (frv[0] == 'Yes') ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE', 
          frv2test = (frv[2] == 'Yes') ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE',
          frv3test = (frv[3] == 'Yes') ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';

      let index = inputB.indexOf(frv[1]);
      if (index > -1) {
        outputO[index]  = [frv0test];
        outputQR[index] = [frv2test, frv3test];
      }
    }
    // write by bulk
    todaysTest.getRange(6, 15, outputO.length, outputO[0].length).setValues(outputO);
    todaysTest.getRange(6, 17, outputQR.length, outputQR[0].length).setValues(outputQR);
  }
}
```

#### Summary of changes:

- Fixed the incorrect last row value of `todaysTestData` by subtracting 5.
- Removed `clearContent` since you are writing `FALSE` after a blank cell which basically removes the tick in the checkbox.
- Used `map` instead to reduce method calls to `SpreadsheetApp`. These `map` functions can be replaced by `getValues` if you see a better `getValues` performance.
- Instead of looping your `todaysTestData`, just use `indexOf` to check what index `frv[1]` is found on the columnB of `todaysTestData` (if there is any) and use that index to write data there.
- Write by bulk using `setValues` instead of looping `setValue`.
- Combine writing `Q` and `R` since they are adjacent columns.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a bunch for your answer. I had to declare both the ```let outputO``` and ```let outputQR``` empty so that I could clear the ranges as cell ```C3``` changes and those are to be empty, but it worked much faster.

Comment: You're welcome @santosOnit. The most important part in improving the runtime of these kinds of scripts is to read and write in bulk. Looping both `getRange` and `setValue` really slow things down when dealing with a large data. And if you can avoid using a loop, that would be better. `indexOf`, `includes` and the likes are your friends here.

Comment: Awesome. To me, learning this new level of abstractions (programming wise) is the next step. Too much to take in as a beginner, but we'll get there! Thank you and have a great weekend!

Comment: Your explanation above is excellent! Just like Tom Peters said: “If not excellence, what? If not excellence now, when?” Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try that...

```
function onEdit(e)
  {
  if ( e.range.getSheet().getName() === 'Todays Tests V2' 
    && e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C3') 
    {
    let 
      formRespSheet  = e.source.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1')
    , formRespRng    = formRespSheet.getRange(2, 13, formRespSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 4)
    , formRespValues = formRespRng.getValues()
    , todaysTest     = e.source.getSheetByName('Todays Tests V2')
    , todaysTestData = todaysTest.getRange(6, 1, todaysTest.getLastRow(), 18).getValues()
      ;
    todaysTest.getRange('O6:O').clearContent();
    todaysTest.getRange('Q6:Q').clearContent();
    todaysTest.getRange('R6:R').clearContent();

    for (const frv of formRespValues)
      {
      let
        frv0test = (frv[0] == 'Yes') ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'
      , frv2test = (frv[2] == 'Yes') ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'
      , frv3test = (frv[3] == 'Yes') ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'
        ;
      todaysTestData.forEach( (ttd,j) =>
        {
        if (frv[1] == ttd[1])
          {
          let j6 = j+6
          todaysTest.getRange(`O${j6}`).setValue( frv0test )
          todaysTest.getRange(`Q${j6}`).setValue( frv2test )
          todaysTest.getRange(`R${j6}`).setValue( frv3test )
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'll test that. Thanks

Comment: Tested it and applied @Octavia Sima's answer above, as I thought I'd stretch it as far as possible. Thanks a lot for your answer!